# Boolean algebra how simplify products of sum Form

Tags: boolean-algebra, products

How Solve it to minimum number of literals

i can't understand basic properties to simplify this expression

$(A̅ +C)(A̅ +C̅ )(C+D)(B̅ +D)(A+B+C̅ D)(A+B̅ +C)$

explain me to understand concepts of simplification!

Comment: You can look for the basic rules like distributive law, associative law, absorption, adsorption, demorgan etc and then use them to simplify it

Comment: @Nilanjan but i am new to these concepts plz can you help me to solve this expression ?

Comment: You can check this [here](http://electronics-course.com/boolean-algebra)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in parts.

$$ (\overline A + C)(\overline A + \overline C) $$

So multiply it out.  8b Distributive Law: $(W + X) • (Y + Z) = W Y + W Z + X Y + X Z$

$$\overline A\ \overline A + \overline A\ \overline C + \overline A C + \overline C C $$
4a Complement Law: $ X • \overline X = 0 $

3a Idempotent Law: $ X • X = X $

$$\overline A + \overline A\ \overline C + \overline A C + 0 $$

2b Identity Law: $ X + 0 = X $

Extract common terms. 8a Distributive Law: $X • (Y + Z) = X Y + X Z$

$$\overline A ( 1 + \overline C + C) $$
$$\overline A $$

1b Annulment Law: $ X + 1 = 1 $

Expression becomes:

$$\overline A (C+D) (\overline B + D) (A + B + \overline C D) (A + \overline B + C)$$

Simplify the next two terms.  Then the last two terms.  Finally simplify the remainders.

Admit-ably, I did the easier part.  Get familiar with a set of rules your instructor gave you.  Then practice.

[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](http://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)